# Can datatables sort a column with an input field?

Tags: datatables

I am trying to make datatables sort my columns. The first column works okay as it's a simple number. However the next column is an input field. When I try to make that sort then nothing happens.

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" class="table sortable no-margin">
<thead>
<tr>
   <th scope="col" class="sorting" style="width: 57px;">
        <span class="column-sort">
        <a href="#" title="Sort up" class="sort-up"></a>
        <a href="#" title="Sort down" class="sort-down"></a>
        </span>
        ID
   </th>
   <th scope="col" class="sorting_desc" style="width: 94px;">
        <span class="column-sort">
        <a href="#" title="Sort up" class="sort-up"></a>
        <a href="#" title="Sort down" class="sort-down"></a>
        </span>
        Order
   </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr id="row_20" class="odd">
    <td id="refKey_20" style="text-align:center;" class="">
        1Y
    </td>
    <td class=" sorting_1">
        <input type="text" value="160" size="3" name="item.Order" 
        maxlength="3" id="Order_20" >
    </td>

</tr>
<tr id="row_19" class="even">
    <td id="refKey_19" style="text-align:center;" class="">
        1X
    </td>
    <td class=" sorting_1">
        <input type="text" value="150" size="3" name="item.Order" 
        maxlength="3" id="Order_19" >
    </td>

</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Is there some way that I can get datatables to sort input fields?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should look at this example that explains how to [do sorting on input fields.](http://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/dom_sort.html) Basically you declare a sorting function

```
/* Create an array with the values of all the input boxes in a column */
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnSortData['dom-text'] = function  ( oSettings, iColumn )
{
    var aData = [];
    $( 'td:eq('+iColumn+') input', oSettings.oApi._fnGetTrNodes(oSettings) ).each( function () {
        aData.push( this.value );
    } );
    return aData;
}
```

And then tell to your table to use that

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "aoColumns": [
        null,
        { "sSortDataType": "dom-text" }
    ]
} );
```

or wit aoColumnDefs

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "aoColumnDefs": [{ "sSortDataType": "dom-text" , aTarget: "yourclass"}]
} );
```

Comment: But I have a problem. I use the same refresh code for different tables. Your code hardcodes the aoColumns.  Is it possible to set these up as classes on the td columns? Or alternatively can I make a different set of "aoColumns" and use different ones for each table?

Comment: @Gemma i usually had to set-up manually aoColumns for each table, i think that you should have different sets of aoColumns and than use them as needed while keeping the other options fixed

Comment: Did you try aoColumnDefs. I am just trying to learn about that. I think that can set based on the class of a th.

Comment: @Gemma, never tried that but it should work, i added that to my answer

Answer (score 12):

The easiest way is to add a hidden span inside columns  `<span style="visibility:hidden">value of the input</span>`

Comment: Nice trick! First hidden span, then the input. all inside the column

Comment: Very nice! simple and easy. In my case I just changed from visibility:hidden to display:none so it doesn't take DOM space. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

For versions of Datatables 1.10+ the names of some option variables have been changed and a new API introduced. Documentation here: http://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/dom_sort.html.

Here is a working version of the above accepted answer in 1.10+:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "orderDataType": "dom-input",
                "targets": 0, // Just the first column
            },
        ],
    });
});
```

The custom sort function:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.order['dom-input'] = function (settings, col) {
    return this.api().column(col, { order: 'index' }).nodes().map(function (td, i) {
        return $('input', td).val();
    });
}
```

Comment: You must add type: 'string' to the columnDefs array object to get it to work on alphanumeric fields

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['textbox-asc'] = function (a, b) {
    var vala = $('#' + $(a).filter('input').attr('id')).val().toLowerCase();
    var valb = $('#' + $(b).filter('input').attr('id')).val().toLowerCase();
    if (vala === '')
        return 1;
    if (valb === '')
        return -1;
    return vala < valb ? -1 : vala > valb ? 1 : 0;
};

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['textbox-desc'] = function (a, b) {
    var vala = $('#' + $(a).filter('input').attr('id')).val().toLowerCase();
    var valb = $('#' + $(b).filter('input').attr('id')).val().toLowerCase();
    if (vala === '')
        return 1;
    if (valb === '')
        return -1;
    return vala < valb ? 1 : vala > valb ? -1 : 0;
};
```

then use it like this

```
 $(datatable).dataTable({
                    "iDisplayLength": 50,
                    "bLengthChange": false,
                    "bPaginate": false,                        
                    "columns": [
                        null, { "sType": "textbox" }
                    ],
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to use the columns option where you are rending information from a JSON file you can easily add a hidden span on your render property. It appears as though DataTables looks for text to order and if it cannot find any, it will break. The example at https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/dom_sort.html uses a table that has already been rendered. Here is an example using an API:

```
...columns([{ 
        "data": "receivedDate",
        "render": function (data, type, row, meta)
        {

            if (data == "null")
            {
                return "<input type='text' id='datepicker_" + meta.row + "' class='datepicker form-control' /><span class='hidden'><span>";
            }
            else
            {
                return "<input type='text' id='datepicker_" + meta.row + "' class='datepicker form-control' value='" + moment(data).format("MM/DD/YYYY") + "'/><span class='hidden'>" + moment(data).format('MM/ DD / YYYY') + "</span>";
            }
        }
    }]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Set an invisible div with the value before the input field.

```
<tbody>
<tr id="row_20" class="odd">
    <td id="refKey_20" style="text-align:center;" class="">
        1Y
    </td>
    <td class=" sorting_1">
        <div style="display:none;">160</div>
        <input type="text" value="160" size="3" name="item.Order" 
        maxlength="3" id="Order_20" >
    </td>

</tr>
<tr id="row_19" class="even">
    <td id="refKey_19" style="text-align:center;" class="">
        1X
    </td>
    <td class=" sorting_1">
        <div style="display:none;">150</div>
        <input type="text" value="150" size="3" name="item.Order" 
        maxlength="3" id="Order_19" >
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: This doesn't work when the input value is edited by the user, without code to update the value on the change event, which seems way too much work.