# In DataTable, how to sort a column by partial value?

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am using DataTables, a Table plug-in for jQuery, as a tool on my web design. But I encounter a problem since I would like to sort a column by partial value.
For example, there is a column named "Speaker", with values "Prof. Lin", "Dr. Yu", "Prof. Chen", and so on. When sorting the column, the order will be: 

1."Dr. Yu" 
2."Prof. Chen" 
3."Prof. Lin". 

I would like to sort by their first name rather than the first letter, which means ordering as: 

1."Prof. Chen" 
2."Prof. Lin" 
3."Dr. Yu".

Another example is a column "Average(5% bias)" with values "78.0 (-2.5~2.5)", "90.5 (-1.5~1.5)", "130.0 (-3.0~3.0)", and so on. When sorting the column, the order will be: 

1."130.0 (-3.0~3.0)" 
2."78.0 (-2.5~2.5)" 
3."90.5 (-1.5~1.5)". 

I would like to sort by their average value rather than the first letter (DataTable thinks the column values are string rather than float), which means ordering as: 

1."78.0 (-2.5~2.5)" 
2."90.5 (-1.5~1.5)" 
3."130.0 (-3.0~3.0)".

 

In my database, there are two columns to store the data, like "title" and "forst_name", "average" and "bias". So it is easy to separate as two parts in a `<td></td>` tag.
Is it possible to sort a column by partial value using DataTables?

Comment: Does the [custom sorting plugins](https://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/) for datatables help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done a [sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/jithin4u/L9684zk3/) for the `Title` sort. You may do the rest for the `Average` column.

### Markup

```
<table id="report">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Dr. Yu</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Prof. Chen</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Prof. Lin</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

### JavaScript/jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function getValue(titleValue) {
        return titleValue.replace(/^Prof\.\s+|^Dr\.\s+/g, '');
    }

    jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['title-asc'] = function (a, b) {
        var x = getValue(a);
        var y = getValue(b);
        return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
    };

    jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['title-desc'] = function (a, b) {
        var x = getValue(a);
        var y = getValue(b);
        return ((x < y) ? 1 : ((x > y) ? -1 : 0));
    };

    $('#report').dataTable({"aoColumns": [
            { "sType": "title" }
        ]});
});
```

Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333079/get-jquery-data-tables-to-sort-on-table-that-contains-inputs)

Comment: Thank you very much!!
I write another function for average data column:

    function getValue(averageValue) {
        return parseFloat(averageValue.substring(0, averageValue.indexOf('(')));
    }