# Best way to render boolean data columns in jquery datatables.net

Tags: jquery, json, datatable, datatables

I am using the [datatables.net](http://datatables.net/) data grid with [jquery](http://jquery.com/) and [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). I have a large chunk of JSON data with some boolean columns in it and would like to render a datatables column as a checked or unchecked checkbox (all with bootstrap styling of course). What is the easiest/fastest was to do this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I answered my own question :-) it's actually very simple:

```
var simple_checkbox = function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
    var is_checked = data == true ? "checked" : "";
    return '<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" ' +
        is_checked + ' />';
}

var setup_datatable = function () {
    $('#data-table').DataTable({
        "columns": [
            { "data": "id", "className": "text-center"},
            { "data": "keywords"},
            { "data": "platform"},
            { "data": "is_active", "render": simple_checkbox},
            { "data": "is_terminated", "render": simple_checkbox}
        ],
        "ajax": "/data"
    }); // DataTable

}
```

Comment: This is great. I think you should accept your own answer, perhaps it will help other people in the future.

Comment: This answer is still valid, but I just saw that it disables the sorting fonctionnality of datatables. I'd like to point to [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376469/#answer-53929269) as a complement which can be integrated very easily.

Answer (score 3):

Adding the disabled class will remove the function on the page but keep the look.

```
var simple_checkbox = function (data, type, full, meta) {
             var is_checked = data == true ? "checked" : "";
             return '<input type="checkbox" **class="checkbox disabled"** ' +
                 is_checked + ' />';
         }
```

Comment: Thanks @eric phillips, thats a great idea

Comment: This is incredibly helpful!  I was so happy to see my checkboxes with checks showing up.  One thing that's odd is when a checkbox is selected, it no longer shows anything until I move to another area and then it renders.  Have you encountered this?

Comment: @Robin. What was causing it for you and how did you fix it?