# I want to sort my table column on input value AFTER setting value

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatables

Newb here...I have a table I created using the jQuery DataTables plugin. Everything is working as expected BUT I added a column that is an input. I'd like for users to be able to sort this column after putting in their values. It is a ranking system that is using quite a long list of items so they need to be able to sort  after entering values so that they can keep track of what numbers they've used up to that point. I am setting my variable to be the input value on keyup but after I set the value, I can't sort the column by clicking on the header. It works for the other columns (from jQuery DataTable plugin). Also, if i hard code some text before if the td (before '+sortRank+') it also works as expected. Why is it not recognizing the values for sorting after I set them with jQuery? Thanks for you help!

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
function GenerateTableFromJson(objArray,objArrayTwo,objArrayThree) {

 var tableContent = '<table summary="GFSTechIntake" id="AllRequestsTable" style="width:100%"><thead><tr><th>Submit Priority</th><th>Your Prev Rank</th><th>Current Overall</th><th>Category</th>' + '<th>Status</th>' +' <th>Request Name</th>' + '<th>Problem Statement</th>' + '<th>Business Benefits</th><th>Dept(s)</th></tr></thead><tbody>';      

    var sortRank = "";

    $('input.title').on('keyup',function(){
        sortRank = $(this).val();
     });

     tableContent += '<tr class="allItemsTr">';
     if(rank != ''){
     tableContent += '<td class="allItemsPriority">'+sortRank+'<input class="title" placeholder=' + rank + ' value='+rank+'></td>';
     } else {
     tableContent += '<td class="allItemsPriority"><input class="title" placeholder=' + rank + '></td>';
     }
     tableContent += '<td class="prevRank">N/A</td>';
     tableContent += '<td class="currentRank">N/A</td>';
 } 

 return tableContent;

 }
```

Comment: Do you want something like [this](https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/dom_sort.html)?

Comment: YES! This made my night. Thanks! I'll mark this as the answer if you'll submit it as an answer.

Comment: Glad that I am able to helped you.. What if I mark your question a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376469/can-datatables-sort-a-column-with-an-input-field)? ;-)

Comment: Yeah, no prob. Thanks again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can datatables sort a column with an input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376469/can-datatables-sort-a-column-with-an-input-field)